# SQL Identity function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, identity

how I can select max value from one table and set in identity function

select identity(int, (select max(column) from table, 1) as id

above query gives expected '+', '-', expected Numeric or integer in select max statement

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database supports an `identity()` function, then the correct syntax would be:

```
select identity(int, (select max(column) from table), 1) as id
```

The subquery needs to be enclosed in parentheses.

I am highly suspicious that this is desirable, but it answers the question you asked.

Comment: sorry just now updated question with the error I am getting which gives ' error expected '+', '-', Numeric or integer in select max statement'